# Sonar findbugs plugin issues in 5.6.3

Tags: sonarqube5.1

We recently upgraded to Sonar 5.6.3, the findbugs plugin 3.4.4 shows lot of warnings and issues eg "The class "abc " could not be matched to its original source file. It might be a dynamically generated class.". We have tried all the options given on net like :
https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-findbugs/issues/51 
but none is working, giving sonar.java.binaries to pointing to .sonar in workspace. Is there any solution to the findbugs issue of sonar 5.6.3 ? Please help.

Comment: Kindly reply as response is highly awaited.